# Wordpress slider not showing up/transparent text/ and missing drop down menu

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have seen this issue on other posts but can't seem to find the answer that fixes my particular site issue.

Site was working fine until it was transferred to another host- had to edit a lot of wordpress php code to get it to work again, but did nothing with the template. www.tnapothecary.com

For whatever reason the visual editor buttons are gone on the wordpress page editor.  I have updated to the lastest wordpress and nothing is still working. Any ideas on how I can get the text to show up again?

The other issue I'm having is the slider is now not showing up and the drop down menu isn't working. I was thinking its a js issue, but after replacing all the theme js and tinymce files- nothing did the trick. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Ben

Comment: Are there any errors in the developer console?

Comment: Whats weird is that I'm now getting this on google page speed analytics  The following requests are returning 404/410 responses. Either fix the broken links, or remove the references to the non-existent resources.
•http://tnapothecary.com/wp-content/themes/gentle/images/favicon.ico
•http://tnapothecary.com/wp-content/themes/gentle/js/easing-jquery.js
-

Comment: Can you verify that those files are where they should be?

Comment: I'm trying another fresh install of the theme (when I clicked different settings within the master panel of the theme they would not load)- files are there- verified their location

Comment: no go on another fresh install- problem still exists

Comment: wp-content/themes/gentle/js/functions.js
(copied the url to clipboard from ftp )
The files are def there.

Comment: Yes, but what about easing-jquery.js?

Comment: wp-content/themes/gentle/js/easing-jquery.js
(they are all there)